# Figure out if Android Facebook app is configured to be used

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I created Android app which can post photo to Facebook. I tested it in case where there is no Facebook app on the device, and it works fine, and I tested it with proper Facebook application which works even better.

A day before release I took an old HTC Desire HD, with Android 2.3.5 and HTC Sense 3.0.

Sense 3.0. comes with FB app pre-installed, that is not configured to be used (it requires synchronization with the phone and inserting FB info).

Now I know that there are few users that do not use this pre-instaled app and that do not have facebook app at all, but is there a way to handle this situation, as my app crashes if there is an app, but it is not configured.

In code I do check only if there is katana or not:

```
// Check if FaceApp is installed
    PackageInfo info = null, info2 = null;
    String packageName = "com.facebook.katana";

    try {
        info = getSherlockActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        Log.w(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Face App not found", e);

    }
```

Additionally, this HTC Sense does not open expected FB login dialog, but some old version of it, saves login information in to sense data (I Assume, not sure) and than Facebook prompts me with an error saying that "page requested cannot be displayed at the moment or it is temporary unavailable..."

how to handle situation like this? Thanks

Thanks.

Comment: hi, did u get a solution  to this ?? i am facing the same issue :(

Comment: No, as far as I recall I was not able to avoid this but common sense says that, if you use facebook, you will have facebook app installed, so I simply left it where it is :S

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when the Facebook app in the Phone is not updated there is no problem of configuration according to me. So please check it after updating.

Comment: That is more precise, I agree. How ever, I want to avoid the potential crash, so I guess I should somehow get the app version information and avoid using it. I can't force users to update FB app if they do not want to ...